# How to add first line and last line value into existing XML file

Tags: java, xml

I have an existing XML file and I just want to add  tag in first line of that XML file and last line of that file I just want to add . How can I achieve this.

Sample Input:

```
 1. 
 2. <suite>
 3.   <class>
 4.   </class>
 5. </suite>
 6.
```

The sample payload hierarchic will look lie above I just want to add line no 1:  and line no 6 . The xml content is dynamic and it can be increase or decrease. But I just want to add the root tag in first and last of the XML file

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already answered your question in last line , you just need to add root element in your xml , for that just parse xml using any parser in java(My language , if you want you can use any other language also) then just add root element. 
cheers :)